# Can Windows Update service break a server when it runs?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server, windows-update

-- Even though it only downloads, and does not install updates?

All 6 users lost access to the database, or network yesterday. I can't find why. There are no errors indicatings something went wrong.

At 15:01:44, the application stopped working for 6 users. I can see this by looking at the busiest table in the database. Updates to it stopped then, at 15:01:44. Nothing more happened for 1 hour after that.

The Application log gives me no help. System Logs show:

```
08/05/2019 13:23:23 The Windows Update service entered the stopped state.
08/05/2019 14:58:49 The Windows Update service entered the running state.
08/05/2019 15:08:50 The Windows Update service entered the stopped state.
08/05/2019 15:37:07 The Windows Update service entered the running state.
08/05/2019 15:47:08 The Windows Update service entered the stopped state.
```

About 3 minutes before it stopped working, Windows Update service started. Although updates are downloaded, they are *not installed*. However I noticed that deferred Update warns you that Windows Update **may update itself** when it runs.

I suspect that Windows Update did update itself and this caused the problem. I can't think of anything else which could've gone wrong.

Is this possible?

Comment: How are the users accessing your database, client applications?

Comment: These are all enabled:
    1 Shared Memory
    2 TCP/IP
    3 Named pipes

In that order. Although Named pipes is enabled, the clients will use TCP/IP.

Clients are running a desktop Winforms program.

Comment: Well, anything's possible!?!...but what does it say in event viewer or system update history?...were new updates installed or not?

Comment: What does the SQL Server log say in relation to this?

Comment: @user1040323 - Can you confirm if the individual users were having any permission on Database instance(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily windows update should not affect the operation of a SQL Server. But you need to eliminate this from your investigation.

The best way to troubleshoot this hypothesis is to check the last updates and hot-fixes to your system. Once you have a list, do a search for the KBs in the Microsoft Knowledge Base and then you can figure out if any of the updates were installed without the need for a restart or could have had an adverse side effect on a network interface.

Also I would check the SQL Logs at the same time and look for unusual behaviour.

[image]